# How to turn on MacBook automatically when it receives power again (and battery was drained)?

Tags: battery, ssh, power, webserver

I would like to use my old MacBook Air (2015) as a server-like machine so that I can connect remotely to it via SSH. I managed to do this, however, I am looking forward how to be able to power it on automatically when there would be a power outage.

I want to accomplish the following things:

1. If the system is overloaded, restart automatically (perhaps this would be unlikely, but just in case)
2. If there is a power outage, and the battery drains too, when the electricity is back, turn the machine on again and login automatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "overloaded"? If you think that power supply failure for longer than the battery lasts is likely (or even possible), then you should buy a UPS. Desktop Macs have a "start after power failure" setting, but it's not available on laptops.

Comment: @benwiggy I refer to the cases in which the software that runs on the computer might use 100% of the CPU for an extended period case, which should trigger a restart. I already use a UPS, but sometimes the outage is extended enough, and the UPS itself goes down.

Comment: What tasks are you running on this server? Normally, you don't want to force quit just because it's doing something intensive.

Comment: @benwiggy Perhaps I will just set up Home Assistant on it. The critical question is the second part: how to power the computer and log in automatically once the electricity comes back.

Comment: I don't think so. You need to look at the `pmset` command. At worst, you could schedule startups regularly, so you would only have to wait until the appointed time.

Comment: @benwiggy Even regular startups would be fine – but the question is how are they triggered? If the battery is drained and then after, let's say two days, I connect it to power, will it restart at that scheduled time?

Comment: Yes, schedule startup times obviously work when the laptop is not yet started.